# Can Runge-Kutta method be used to solve non-linear differential equation?

Tags: classical-mechanics, computational-physics, differential-equations

Consider two-body central force problem in polar co-ordinates $r, \theta$. Corresponding 2nd order differential equation is obtained by using conservation of angular momentum. This equation is :

$$ \frac{d^2 r}{dt^2} = \frac{l^2}{m^2r^3} - \frac{GM}{r^2}$$

where $r(t)$ is radial position of particle (of mass $m$) as a function of time $t$, $l$ is angular momentum which is constant, $G$ is gravitational constant & $M$ is mass of the heavier body, assumed to be at rest at the origin of co-ordinate system i.e. at $(r,\theta)=(0,0)$.

I want to solve above non-linear differential equation; it is non-linear since dependent variable $r$ has powers -3 and -2 on RHS.

Can I use 4-order Runge-Kutta method to solve this equation ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about implementation details of a computational problem.

Comment: I have a sincere question probably coming from my pow ignorance: why can't you use the method? The only problem here I think is that you take $(r,\theta) = (0,0)$ and it can cause problems because the right side of the equation and the meaning of $\theta$ itself are ill-defined. Is there any reason this method won't work if you take the same initial conditions but with $r=0.01$?

Comment: @OfekGillon: $\theta$ is not ill-defined. Actually we have two different 2-order differential equations (coupled) : one for $r$ and another for $\theta$. Conservation of angular momentum de-couples them and reduces to one equation given above. ...Also if we try to solve above 1-Dim equation analytically, we end up in the solution of the form $t(r)$ i.e. time is function of $r$. So we have to invert that into $r(t)$. And this inversion process can be extremely difficult in practice. Please see standard textbook on classical mechanics e.g. by Goldstein (Chapter 3).

Comment: @OfekGillon: Here Initial conditions should be on $r$ and $dr/dt$, if we want to solve numerically. But if we want to solve analytically we need initial conditions as Total Energy and Angular momentum of the mass $m$. I am also bit confused here.

Comment: @DavidZ: Seems to me this falls under [point #1](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/computational-physics/info): *We can advise on numerical methods when tied to a physical problem and not a generic P/ODE*.

Comment: Would [scicomp.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: @KyleKanos I think that tag wiki may be a little too permissive, under your interpretation. I'm going by the [help center](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) which says that questions about implementation details are off topic. I wouldn't say the question here is tied to a particular problem. But it is close.

Comment: @DavidZ: I wrote it and it's pretty much a verbatim copy of meta q/5603 (covering both answers). I would also argue that this question is not at all about writing, compiling, debugging or optimizing code (which is what is explicitly marked as off-topic); it's asking *Can this numerical method be applied to this physical situation?*

Comment: @KyleKanos Yeah, I noticed and edited my comment. Well, I still think this question should be off topic because it doesn't tie the computational question to the physical problem, but I no longer believe so strongly enough to have closed it unilaterally.

Comment: What makes you think it *couldn't* be used? Have you looked at what other people simulating bodies in orbit use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For that kind of problem a symplectic integrator will give more physically accurate results, since solutions will preserve the energy and angular momenta. You will get a better long term predictions.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_integrator

http://astro.pas.rochester.edu/~aquillen/phy411/lecture7.pdf

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can. The only caveat with numerically solving non-linear ODE's exists when the derivative function is discontinuous in some way. For example a sliding block with dry friction. The direction of friction can switch at an instant and care must be taken not to step over such event. Similarly with collisions.

In your case, I think the derivative function is smooth and continuous if the radial distances $r$ are large enough. To get good results I would focus a lot on time step management. Remember the RK4 scheme is equivalent to fitting cubic splines into the motion and so care must be taken to set the time steps so the results have sufficient geometrical accuracy.